# LaunchFile doesn't show on my device ios 9, xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen, launchimage

When I launch the application on the simulator the "splash screen" launch file appears, but when I launch the app on my iOS device it doesn't appear

I have the launchImage in the assets with the different size of the images like apple suggest.

I've deleted my LaunchScreenfile.storyboard because I don't have to use it.

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator and the device. Then do a clean build. BTW - You should a LaunchScreen instead of launch images. You have to if you wish to support the new iPad Pro. You should also be using Xcode 7.1, not 7.0.

Comment: I'm sorry , I'm using Xcode7.1 @rmaddy , And yes thanks you a lot. I've deleted my app from the device and Launch it again and works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to delete the application from my device, did a clean build and relaunch the app.

like @rmaddy suggest me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget setting this in project file[image]